# Position of words in sprintf strings for translation

Tags: internationalization, printf, translate, poedit

In some languages, the words do not have the same position.

Here is an example:

```
sprintf( __( '%s left a %s on %s\'s %s.', 'o2' ), $commentAuthor, $commentLink, $postAuthor, $postLink );
```

This string returns for example:

**John**(1) left a **comment**(2) on **Jane**(3)'s **post**(4).

But in French, some words are not in the same position:

**John**(1) a laissé un **commentaire**(2) sur la **publication**(4) de **Jane**(3).

I translated the string in poedit:

```
%s a laissé un %s sur la %s de %s.
```

But the words are misplaced:

**John**(1) a laissé un **commentaire**(2) sur la **Jane**(3) de **publication**(4).

This is not a correct translation.

How to change the order with poedit or any other translation editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution:

```
sprintf( __( '%1$s left a %2$s on %3$s\'s %4$s.', 'o2' ), $commentAuthor, $commentLink, $postAuthor, $postLink );
```

In poedit:

```
%1$s a laissé un %2$s sur la %4$s de %3$s.
```